# Sufficient ESS in MCMC

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo

Is there any rule of thumb to determine whether the ESS are sufficient to conclude that the sample are independent ? I know how to calculate ESS but not really sure how to interpret them or give a proper explanation whether the sample observation are independent

Comment: Perfect sampling (Fill, 1998) turns MCMC algorithms into iid generators, when applicable. Similarly, renewal (Hobert & X, 2004) can turn an MCMC kernel into an iid generator.

Answer (score 2):

The theoretical ESS of a Markov kernel is

1. measures the modification in the asymptotic variance due to autocorrelation
2. is unknown in most cases, thus need be estimated
3. varies with the parameterisation of the chain, ie the ESS for the chain $X_t$ is different from the ESS for the chain $g(X_t)$

[Vehtari (2021)](https://avehtari.github.io/rhat_ess/ess_comparison.html) offers a very nice entry on the performances of four different ESS estimates and on the dependence on the parameterisation. The Markov chain under study is an AR(1) sequence. His conclusion is that

> In our experiments, Geyer’s (1992) truncation had superior stability
> compared to flat-top (Doss et al., 2014) and slug-sail (Vats and
> Knudson, 2021) lag window approaches.

[image]

**Ref.**

Vehtari, A., Gelman, A., Simpson, D., Carpenter, B., Bürkner, P.-C. (2021): Rank-normalization, folding, and localization: An improved Rˆ for assessing convergence of MCMC. Bayesian analysis, 16(2):667—718. [doi:10.1214/20-BA1221](https://doi.org/10.1214/20-BA1221).

Answer (score 1):

Pedantic technical comment: I'm not convinced we can achieve *independent* samples from our MC algorithms in all cases. I think we can realistically aim for *unautocorrelated* samples.

Aim for $\text{ESS} = N$ where $N$ is the number of (retained) iterations in your Markov chain. Remember that ESS = "Effective sample size". In an ideal world, the effective size of a sample should be the actual size of the sample.

If $\text{ESS} < N$ then you should consider

1. Thinning your chain (keeping only every $k$-th sample). This reduces the effect of autocorrelation on the samples.
2. Increasing the amount of burn-in (discarding the first $B$ samples). In many circumstances, the MC has to "wander towards" the region of high posterior density, if you keep this burn-in phase, you will decrease the ESS of your chain.
3. Using a different MC algorithm. For example, changing the proposal mechanism of the MCMC scheme. Some algorithms are better suited to some tasks than others. Impossible to say what will work better without any additional information.

You can also perform other diagnostics to check for uncorrelated samples. For instance, plot/compute autocorrelation coefficients of each parameter. If the plotted coeffs are all $\approx 0$, it is likely you have achieved an unautocorrelated sample.