# Metropolis Hastings Algorithms: How to measure the performance of algorithms? (Multidimensional)

Tags: sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings, mcmc-acceptance-rate

I am working on a project and I am trying to measure the performance and compare two MCMC algorithms. The one is Random-Walk MH and the second one is PCN.

I thought of maybe comparing the mean absolute difference between the inferred and actual variable, which I did. Also, I am not sure whether the acceptance rate is a goo metric.
Do you have any suggestions? Online I could only find for 1D comparison such as the Trace plots and ACF.

Thank you!

Comment: Effective sample size [(ESS)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/571539/7224), [mean square jumping distance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/12185/7224)

Comment: Dear Professor Thank you. Also I ws re-thinking the 1D methods I suggested. Using the algorithms I draw N-dimensional vectors. Does it make sense to make trace plots and ACF for each dimension (I believe it's wrong but since they are data points of the space we want to explore, just need to confirm)